# List doesn't have ID field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, id

I'm trying to add an ID field to the sharepoint list view. I am working on SharePoint online list(tied to a powerapps solution).

I have been following the instructions online, "Edit View", find ID etc. but I have not found the ID option in settings.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the screenshot of view settings page so that it will be easy for us to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Go to list settings.
2. Select your view in which you want to add the ID column.
3. Select checkbox near ID field in the list of fields given on view settings page.
4. Click Save/OK.

**Note**:

1. Please make sure that the display name of ID field is not been changed by you or any other user.
2. You are seeing the correct view in which you have added the ID column.

Comment: Nevermind, I realised I accidentally renamed it to something else. Thanks Ganesh.

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer if it helped you in any way.